# /mnt/nvme0n1 already mounted or mount point busy

Tags: centos, fedora, filesystems, chroot, root-filesystem

I am trying to mount nvme /dev/nvme0n1 to /mnt/chroot

I have created the directory /mnt/chroot

when I "sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1 /mnt/chroot" I get "mount: /mnt/chroot: /dev/nvme0n1 already mounted or mount point busy."

I have tried on an arch live usb and now on a Fedora 30 live usb.

```
findmnt /dev/nvme0n1
```

returns nothing meaning nvme0n1 is not mounted.  But how can the mount point be busy if I just created the mount directory /mnt/chroot and nvme0n1 is not mounted?

My objective is to build chroot with root, `/sys`, `/proc`, `/boot` and `/boot/efi` mounted.

I'm weak on the cli for this task.

```
lsblk -f

NAME            FSTYPE            LABEL                     UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0           squashfs                                                                                          
loop1           ext4              Anaconda                  b44431ef-901f-4c18-9b7b-224b8bb98af6                  
├─live-rw       ext4              Anaconda                  b44431ef-901f-4c18-9b7b-224b8bb98af6    822.1M    87% /
└─live-base     ext4              Anaconda                  b44431ef-901f-4c18-9b7b-224b8bb98af6                  
loop2                                                                                                             
└─live-rw       ext4              Anaconda                  b44431ef-901f-4c18-9b7b-224b8bb98af6    822.1M    87% /
sda                                                                                                               
├─sda1          vfat                                        1078-26A1                                             
├─sda2          xfs                                         7d8928c4-baa1-4eaa-a13c-e937031f8dfa                  
└─sda3          LVM2_member                                 OjAFDa-Il7s-Vj0h-Lian-culw-97um-9GYjOo                
  ├─centos-swap swap                                        df903e75-89f5-4646-aad1-981f17e032e9                  [SWAP]
  ├─centos-home xfs                                         c3dea145-a219-4896-ae9f-8419f91a13aa                  
  └─centos-root xfs                                         66a1a58a-c06f-4407-8d47-1fd4266c6b75                  
sdb             ext4              ssd2                      0be3be76-a16d-4777-ab09-c7cc372ed1bc                  
└─sdb1          ext4              ssd2                      c90f13b9-f228-4051-a586-7b6083f50105                  
sdc             linux_raid_member orcacomputers.orcainbox:0 4ca9118c-3a55-7d0f-db72-3ff2e8b9a521                  
└─md127         ext4                                        d52b3913-2ed2-4142-9309-3fdf641141f0                  
sdd             linux_raid_member orcacomputers.orcainbox:0 4ca9118c-3a55-7d0f-db72-3ff2e8b9a521                  
└─md127         ext4                                        d52b3913-2ed2-4142-9309-3fdf641141f0                  
sde             linux_raid_member orcacomputers.orcainbox:0 4ca9118c-3a55-7d0f-db72-3ff2e8b9a521                  
└─md127         ext4                                        d52b3913-2ed2-4142-9309-3fdf641141f0                  
sdf             iso9660           ARCH_202010               2020-10-01-15-07-58-00                                
├─sdf1          iso9660           ARCH_202010               2020-10-01-15-07-58-00                       0   100% /run/media/liveuser/ARCH_202010
└─sdf2          vfat              ARCHISO_EFI               137A-1EE8                                             
sdg             iso9660           Fedora-WS-Live-30-1-2     2019-04-26-02-34-40-00                                
├─sdg1          iso9660           Fedora-WS-Live-30-1-2     2019-04-26-02-34-40-00                       0   100% /run/initramfs/live
├─sdg2          vfat              ANACONDA                  E385-716D                                             
└─sdg3          hfsplus           ANACONDA                  8f5370e2-fd7c-3f3a-9d01-aa72345be183                  
sr0                                                                                                               
nvme0n1                                                                                                           
├─nvme0n1p1     LVM2_member                                 CjuOUt-h2bH-EjCp-ALwd-c8BW-ZckJ-cpB322                
├─nvme0n1p2     LVM2_member                                 M1em0l-TY0y-ZuIt-DK2i-0yJp-OHNz-7RfupC                
│ └─nvmeVg-var  ext4                                        3985016b-fa34-44ca-96ad-7c2e5d5f8221                  
├─nvme0n1p3     LVM2_member                                 qkaPsI-FLzs-wt4Y-bnhm-BpGK-aOcR-fheulP                
│ ├─nvmeVg-var  ext4                                        3985016b-fa34-44ca-96ad-7c2e5d5f8221                  
│ ├─nvmeVg-home ext4                                        540c7358-e018-43bc-b692-6e2398911b38                  
│ └─nvmeVg-root ext4                                        6f9437cd-c9af-4f88-a9b4-7d98e46979aa                  
├─nvme0n1p4     LVM2_member                                 CTkIFV-Ebvf-Ps5w-rysY-s7U0-VLhs-6jLVRV                
│ └─nvmeVg-home ext4                                        540c7358-e018-43bc-b692-6e2398911b38                  
├─nvme0n1p5     LVM2_member                                 Sjii2Q-zkwB-9Nhb-0g6o-4rt3-O9gy-4CMtEI                
│ └─nvmeVg-home ext4                                        540c7358-e018-43bc-b692-6e2398911b38                  
├─nvme0n1p6     LVM2_member                                 QLUYbk-TzNY-RZHz-ck60-gbqA-kPtk-QT2Tm4                
│ └─nvmeVg-root ext4                                        6f9437cd-c9af-4f88-a9b4-7d98e46979aa                  
├─nvme0n1p7     LVM2_member                                 nQg41G-8A3m-wMog-LBzJ-U09n-W1md-lgVEdQ                
│ └─nvmeVg-root ext4                                        6f9437cd-c9af-4f88-a9b4-7d98e46979aa                  
├─nvme0n1p8     LVM2_member                                 D5HOGp-nLA3-zypn-edIj-uPon-Pzrj-N6JcB5                
├─nvme0n1p9     LVM2_member                                 puKdcF-J2PT-THK1-nSqx-RMhe-98ZB-EnDPV0                
├─nvme0n1p10    LVM2_member                                 0XEQEc-pHGc-2B02-d4lp-581f-ZMYv-vKTgpG                
├─nvme0n1p11    LVM2_member                                 NF82AB-ZUaP-D9FF-PLVP-HMuA-pWFz-NIZFRG                
└─nvme0n1p12    ext4                                        3e5f9f87-3178-4ae3-bc51-f0f5134c5fb6          

df -h

Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs              32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 32G  2.8M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                 32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdg1            1.9G  1.9G     0 100% /run/initramfs/live
/dev/mapper/live-rw  6.4G  5.6G  823M  88% /
tmpfs                 32G   76K   32G   1% /tmp
vartmp                32G     0   32G   0% /var/tmp
tmpfs                6.3G  3.5M  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdf1            681M  681M     0 100% /run/media/liveuser/ARCH_202010
```

Comment: I've flagged the question because "please hold my hand while I step through an unfamiliar process" isn't really a question. There is plenty of documentation out there about how to build a chroot, so you'll need to go do some research and then come ask a question if you run into problems (and if no one has ever asked the question before).

Comment: Edited for a question.  I found your quotation useful.  Thank you.

Comment: Mind if we have a look at output from `lsblk -f` and `df -h`?

Comment: added.  Do you get an update when I edit the post? thus making my "added" comment useless?

Comment: Nah, I only get notified about your comments, so you did good. I would probably be notified if I bookmarked the question (there's a little bookmark button). But I don't usually bookmark questions.

Answer (score 1):

`nvme0n1` is a device, which contains partitions `nvme0n1p1`, `nvme0n1p2` and so on.

You can mount only a filesystem, not a device with partitions on it.

Comment: So sda3-centos-root is where the OS is. So how do I mount that? "mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/anydirectory"? I have moved centos-home to the nvme0n1

Answer (score 0):

turns out sda was not mounted so I make a new directory and mounted to the new directory and it worked fine.